# How add nested attributes in the seeds file Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model Exhibit and he have quiz. In quiz we have questions and answers belongs to it. I used nested attributes.

Where I make mistake, because wright now after rake db:seed rails add me only last line in Question. Here is example one of my seeds exhibit

```
e1 = Exhibit.create(
title: 'TITLE', 
author:  'PICASOO',
date_of_origin: '300', 
description: 'LOREM IPSUM', 
ex_id: '1',
type: nil,
    questions_attributes:[
    content: "QUESTION 1?",
        answers_attributes:[
        content: "ANSWER 1",
        correct: true,
        content: "ANSWER 2",
        correct: false, # if it's correct answer i change this var.
        content: "ANSWER 3",
        correct: false]
    ])
```

Exhibit model:

```
has_many :questions, :dependent=> :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, 
                                :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, 
                                :allow_destroy => true
```

Question model:

```
 belongs_to :exhibit
      has_many :answers, :dependent=> :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers,
                                    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, 
                                    :allow_destroy => true
```

Answer model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: remove every `,` after each answer's `correct` attribute. Check my answer carefully to find the difference.

Comment: updated my answer. Please check if the added code works or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
e1 = Exhibit.create(
title: 'TITLE', 
author:  'PICASOO',
date_of_origin: '300', 
description: 'LOREM IPSUM', 
ex_id: '1',
type: nil,
{ 
:questions_attributes => 
    { 0 => 
        { 
           content: "Q1",
           :answers_attributes => 
              { 0 =>
                  {
                      content: "ANSWER 1",
                      correct: true
                  },
                1 =>
                  {
                      content: "ANSWER 2",
                      correct: false
                  }
              }
        }  
    }  
}
)
```

or:

```
e1 = Exhibit.create(
title: 'TITLE', 
author:  'PICASOO',
date_of_origin: '300', 
description: 'LOREM IPSUM', 
ex_id: '1',
type: nil,
questions_attributes: [
  { 
     content: 'Q1',
     answers_attributes: [
       {content: "A1", correct: false},
       {content: "A2", correct: true}
     ]
   }
 ]
)
```